# Incorrect type of ClaimsIdentity read from session cookie after recycling of worker process

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, claims-based-identity

In a VS 2012 / .NET 4.5 / ASP.NET MVC 4 application I have a custom identity type derived from `ClaimsIdentity`. It just adds a few readonly properties to the base class that read values from some claims for convenience:

```
public class AppIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
{
    public AppIdentity(IEnumerable<Claim> claims) : base(claims, "Custom")

    public string CustomProp { get { return FindFirst("CustomClaim").Value; } }
    // etc.
}
```

In a custom `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` I convert the incoming principal into a principal that wraps the above identity, create a token for this principal and write the token to a cookie:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim("CustomClaim", "CustomValue"),
    // etc.
};
var newPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new AppIdentity(claims));
var sessionToken = new SessionToken(newPrincipal, TimeSpan,FromHours(24));
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule
    .WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
```

If I fetch the identity for subsequent requests in a controller action like so...

```
var identity = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;
```

...I find that sometimes the runtime type of `identity` is `AppIdentity` and sometimes it is only its base type `ClaimsIdentity`. My custom claims are always present inside of the `Claims` collection of `identity`.

The identity seems to "lose" the type `AppIdentity` that I expect when the worker process gets recycled. I'm only using an IIS Express development server in this project at the moment and I can force this behaviour when I do a small change in web.config for example. After that the identity always has the type `ClaimsIdentity` and not `AppIdentity` anymore.

Question: Is this approach to save a custom claims identity type in a cookie wrong and possibly not supported? Does a session cookie store the type information of a derived `ClaimsIdentity` at all (which would be necessary, I guess, to materialize the correct identity type from the cookie)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type identity gets lost during serialization roundtrips. I wrote about it here:
http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/08/custom-claims-principals-in-net-4-5/

Comment: Thanks! I've removed the derived identity and adopted the extension method approach.

Comment: Where would we be without the hard work of leastprivilege...?!?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple `HttpModule` that checks the incoming identity in the principal, and converts it to your own implementation

```
public class MyClaimsAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostAuthenticateRequest += Context_PostAuthenticateRequest;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Nothing to dispose, method required by IHttpModule
    }

    void Context_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var transformer = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthenticationManager;
        if (transformer != null)
        {
            var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
            var principal = context.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

            var oo = principal.Identity is DaIdentity;
            if (!oo)
                principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new DaIdentity(principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity));

            var transformedPrincipal = transformer.Authenticate(context.Request.RawUrl, principal);

            context.User = transformedPrincipal;
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = transformedPrincipal;
        }
    }
}
```

And then register it in Web.config like this

```xml
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

      <add name="TestAuthenticationModule" Type="MyAssemby.MyClaimsAuthenticationModule, MyAssembly" preCondition="managedHandler" />



      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
```